# MySQL - MyISAM multi-table delete (similar to ON CASCADE DELETE)

Tags: myisam, multi-table-delete

I'm looking to delete all entries that are referenced by a record, and all the children in different tables as well. If possible I'd like to use a multi-table delete statement as opposed to triggers.

For example

```
Table: forms
id     var
1      foo
2      bar

Table 2: form_options
id     form_id     var
1      1           blah
2      2           hello
3      2           world

Table 3: form_options_info
id     form_options_id     var
1      3                   world info
```

So given the above type of table struct, if I delete row 2 from `forms` that would delete row 2,3 from `form_options` as well as row 1 from `form_options_info`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee not the best solution, but it works:

```
DELETE FROM form_options_info, form_options, forms
  USING forms INNER JOIN form_options INNER JOIN form_options_info
  WHERE (form_options_info.form_options_id = form_options.id 
    AND form_options.form_id = forms.id
    OR form_options.form_id = forms.id)
    AND forms.id = 2;
```

...or just change the tables to InnoDB ;-)...